# Block direct external IP access for GCP's HTTP Load Balancer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

I was wondering if someone knows how to block the HTTP access to an external IP provided by Google's Load Balancer, so you can **just access it** using the domain name.

For example:

- An user open a browser and navigate to `http://IP` -> **Block** the access or **forward** traffic to `https://example.com`

I know some providers offers "this" (like Cloudflare), but I am in Google Cloud, and the documentation hasn't helped me a lot.

Someone knows how to achieve this?, do I need an extra configuration/service?

Comment: You will need Cloud Armor. Create a rule that checks for an HTTP Host header matching your domain(s). Note: Requests always arrive via the IP address. That translation is performed by DNS servers. Direct requests to an IP address and not to **example.com** will not have an HTTP Host header unless manually added. Think about what you are trying to accomplish. Having a dedicated IP address for your load balancer is a positive in most cases. Other services require the HTTP Host header because they share IP addresses among services.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As John Hanley mentioned, you can achieve this by applying a cloud armor rule, checking the HTTP headers. Like this:

[image]

You must define the "greater" policy to **deny** all incoming request, and add a rule like the above to allow just the request with the corresponding **Host** (**:authority** for HTTP/2) header.

A note to consider is that this method **does not** work for backend buckets services (for now).

Comment: Good self-answer. Cloud Armor rules also do not work for objects that Cloud CDN has **already** cached.

Comment: To whoever gets here this days: Anyone could set a fake host header. I don't know how the :authority header is handled on Google Cloud, but I would not trust it unless you know how it's set by the proxy. The safer way would be to restrict Cloudflare IP address on Cloud Armor